# Can an application modify files that are in a password protected folder?

Tags: passwords, malware, ransomware

Specifically regarding Win 10 and [this method of password protecting a directory](http://laptopmag.com/articles/password-protect-folder-windows-10).

Would a malicious application be able to modify files placed in this directory or would it be stopped?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, absolutely, a malicious application could easily modify the files placed in a directory “protected” like this. The reason for this is that the method outlined in the article, **doesn’t provide any protection whatsoever**. All that’s happening here, is that when you ‘protect’ the folder, you set a marker that prevents windows from showing the files (it sets the ‘system’ and ‘hidden’ attributes). After you enter the correct password, this 'marker' is removed again.

This gives the illusion of protection because by default windows is set up so that ‘hidden’ and ‘system’ files are not shown to the user.

However, in fact your files are not protected at all – **they remain accessible all along**. Applications completely ignore the system & hidden setting. Users can enable "show hidden files" and disable "hide protected operating system files" to make the files appear again. Once this is done, they can use the files at will, completely bypassing the password protection in literally a few clicks.

[image]

Properly password protecting files without additional software so that no one (whether human or application) can access/modify them (without the correct password) is a feature that Windows simply doesn’t have, so the only way to actually password protect your files is to use additional software. If you are looking for an easy-to-use solution, I would suggest Safeplicity (https://www.safeplicity.com), but I am biased, so don’t take my word for it and be sure to check out some alternatives. If you’re looking for a free open-source solution, VeraCrypt is probably the best.

One last word of caution: when choosing the software, make sure that it not only password protects your files, but also encrypts them. Password protection without encryption (like the one suggested in the article) can be bypassed by any computer-savvy person (or well written app) with ease – we have seen many lives ruined because of this. Password protection with encryption cannot be broken by anyone (unless you believe in conspiracy theories).

Answer (score 0):

Well, that depends. When the UAC prompt comes up asking you to allow a program to use root privileges do you say yes? If so, then it most certainly could. If you are more cautious, and don't blindly click yes, then maybe not. However there are also ways for attackers to take advantage of system vulnerabilities and inject a malicious payload and gain root privileges without even prompting you. A famous example would be the [ms08-067 SMB exploit](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/7104/) in conjunction with [meterpreter](https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/about-meterpreter/). However that is mainly used on Windows XP based systems without a firewall. Windows 10 makes it a little more difficult. Anyways, root access will not give an attacker immediate access to a password protected folder, but they will then have endless resources to use to circumvent the password. The attacker could certainly delete it from the filesystem though.